# How to replace variable placeholders in a YAML file with nested values from a JSON file using a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a specific CI/CD build step where I need to take environment variables from a nested JSON file and match/replace them in a YAML file.

For example, in my JSON file:

```
{
    "development": {
        "ENV1": "My Value"
    }
}
```

I would then define a YAML file with a placeholder for `${development.ENV1}`:

```
env_variables:
  ENV1: ${development.ENV1}
```

So that when my bash script runs, it updates the file like this:

```
env_variables:
  ENV1: "My Value"
```

I found a reference to be able to do this with environment variables by exporting values and using `envsubst` from this [google community builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/blob/092aa9035d790e9a1f81cf8adf2a1e1f8ec6c812/envsubst/entrypoint.bash#L50) like so:

```
for f in $(ls ${files[*]}); do
    echo "Pre-processing ${f}..." >&2
    cat ${f} | envsubst ${shell_format:+"${shell_format}"} > ${f}.processed
    mv ${f}.processed ${f}
done
```

But I'm not quite sure how to do this equivalent with nested JSON. This is my first "true" foray in to bash, so I'm learning as I go!

Comment: just a side note regarding file names, please read [Filenames and Pathnames in Shell: How to do it Correctly, David A. Wheeler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37210472)